# Angular Nativescript visibility defaults to true, even when variable is initialized

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Is there a way to default "hide" an element in Nativescript?

I have in my component

```
export class HouseholdContactComponent{
  private isLoading = true
}
```

and in my xml

```
<StackLayout [visibility]="isLoading ? 'collapse' : 'visible'">
  <Label text="Hi there"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

With this code, the screen flashes the "Hi there" message and then it goes away.

Comment: Why not use `ngIf`?

Comment: I used the code you have shared and solved my issue. Thanks for asking ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using the [visibility] property, you should use the Angular `*ngIf` directive.

```html
<StackLayout *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <Label text="Hi there"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

On a side note, in order to bind to a attribute property and bind it to interpolation Angular is doing you need to prefix it with `attr`, for example you would need to write `[attr.visibility]` rather than just `[visibility]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [*ngIf directive](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/ng-directives#ngif-directive).  It will render if the variable value is `true`.

Ex:

```
//HTML
<Button text="Show/hide block" (tap)="onTap()" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"></Button>
<GridLayout *ngIf="isVisible" class="bg-primary" borderRadius="2" height="300"></GridLayout>

//Component
...
    onTap() {
        if (this.isVisible) {
            this.isVisible = false;
        } else  {
            this.isVisible = true;
        }
    }
...
```